# SysVinit doesn't run spring boot application in background mode

Tags: java, linux, spring-boot, ubuntu

I'm trying to run spring boot application in linux using SysVinit
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-app-as-a-service

As I know it shoulds run application jar in background and writes log to */var/log/my-app.log* and then I'm able to check the status and logs of this service

But in my case it constantly shows all logs (starting application logs and new upcoming logs) in console and block the console until I enterrupted the process
And when I tried to check the logs in other linux terminal It shows that file with logs doesn't exist

The most strange thing that when I'm trying to check the service status It tries to start service again, when it even alredy started

I'm using Ubuntu-22.04.5 LTS with WSL2 for my goals

I've tried to run it in Amazon EC2 instance following the same steps to configure linux service and It worked properly, but in Windows on-prem VM I've got that issue

Hope for your help

I've tried other versions of local Ubuntu. I want to make it runs in background

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of missing details in this, but I'll try to break it into some simple pieces.

First question is really: how are you launching it? If you're launching it using `java -jar service.jar` then it will not integrate with any of the launch services. If you invoke it by direct execution `./service.jar` then it will use the helper script that is embedded at the beginning of the jarfile, which will perform the creation of the pidfile, the logfile and running the jarfile in the background.

The lines:

```
<configuration>
    <executable>true</executable>
</configuration>
```

in the `pom.xml`, in the build plugin are what's used to ensure that this helper script is injected at the start of the jarfile.

If you don't have this in your pomfile, you end up with a plain jar. If you attempt to launch it, and you're getting an error like: `cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`, then it indicates that you don't have this helper scaffold for your service.

I created a *very* [simple springboot application](https://github.com/anya-evergreen/simple-spring-boot), which works properly under WSL2 when I symlink to it:

```
$ sudo ln -s /home/anysh/simple-script-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /etc/init.d/curly
$ sudo chown anysh:anysh /home/anysh/simple-script-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
$ sudo service curly start
Started [383]
$ cat /var/log/curly.log
: omitted
```

I get the lines related to the pid being created, etc.

You're probably also better off using the instructions for systemd, as that's the default startup manager for ubuntu 22.04.X and bypass the legacy approach. You can configure WSL2 to enable systemd, by having the following in your `/etc/wsl.conf` file:

```
[boot]
systemd=true
```

And then you restart your WSL2 environment (`wsl --shutdown` from powershell or a plain cmd) and then relaunch ubuntu.

Follow the instructions on the page, under section 3.2, for systemd, noting, however that the text `SuccessExitStatus=143` should actually be on the following line.

This will give you a different output when you run it:

```
$ sudo systemctl status curly
○ curly.service - My curly Service
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/curly.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)

Mar 13 19:33:00 chumbawumba simple-script-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar[528]: restTemplateBuilderConfigurer
```